# PHP, Radio Buttons return on, not value

Tags: php, radio-button

Sorry if this is a really simple question, I am just learning php, but I've been writing a script that can create quizzes, and right now html hates me. When I click a radio button and submit my form the result is always that the button is on, not the value I assign it. Here is the excerpt of my code:

```
echo '<form action="index.php" method="get">';
for ($i=0; $i<$_SESSION["fsize"];$i++)
{
    echo 'Type of Answer for Question ' . $i + 1 . ": <br> ";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="radio">Radio Buttons <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="text">Text area <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="Checkboxes">Checkboxes <br>';
```

The html of my page, which is very incomplete, generated by my php is this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Number of questions: 
<input type="number" name="fsize">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<form action="index.php" method="get"> 
1: 
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f0 value="radio">
Radio Buttons 
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f0 value="text"> 
Text area  
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f0 value="Checkboxes"> 
Checkboxes  
<br> 
1:  
<br>  
<input type="radio" name="f1 value="radio"> 
Radio Buttons  
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f1 value="text"> 
Text area  
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f1 value="Checkboxes"> 
Checkboxes  
<br> 
1:  
<br>  
<input type="radio" name="f2 value="radio"> 
Radio Buttons  
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f2 value="text"> 
Text area  
<br> 
<input type="radio" name="f2 value="Checkboxes"> 
Checkboxes  
<br> 
<input type="submit"> 
\n  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I specifically switched to get rather than post so I could see my results, and this is the important part of my url `/index.php?f0+value%3D=on&f1+value%3D=on&f2+value%3D=on`

Does anyone know how I can get it to submit properly? and if you want to see the full php script here it is:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post"> Number of questions: <input type="number"
name="fsize">';
echo '<input type="submit"></form>';
if (isset($_POST["fsize"]))
{
$_SESSION["fsize"] = $_POST["fsize"];
}
if (isset($_SESSION["fsize"]))
{
echo '<form action="index.php" method="get">';
for ($i=0; $i<$_SESSION["fsize"];$i++)
{
    echo 'Type of Answer for Question ' . $i + 1 . ": <br> ";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="radio">Radio Buttons <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="text">Text area <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . ' value="Checkboxes">Checkboxes <br>';
    if (isset($_GET["f" . $i]))
    {
        $_SESSION["f".$i] = $_GET["f".$i];
        echo "I exist!";
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION["f".$i]))
    {
        echo '<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> What is the question? </textarea>';
        switch($_SESSION["f".$i])
        {
            case("radio"):
                echo "you chose a radio button!";
                break;
            case("text"):
                echo "You chose a text area!";
                break;
            case("Checkboxes"):
                echo "You chose checkboxes!";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_GET["f".$i]))
    {
        echo '<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> What is the question? </textarea>';
        switch($_GET["f".$i])
        {
            case("radio"):
                echo "you chose a radio button!";
                break;
            case("text"):
                echo "You chose a text area!";
                break;
            case("Checkboxes"):
                echo "You chose checkboxes!";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
echo '<input type="submit"> </form>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a few other problems with it too I know, but this is the most infuriating.
Sorry about the length, Hovestar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've forgot a closing " in each name attribute of your radio controls:

```
<input type="radio" name="f0" value="radio">
<!--                        ^ this here is important -->
```

Therefore, your browser thinks this radio's name attribute is `"f0 value="` and is missing a value attribute. Therefore it adds the default attribute `on`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel really stupid now, it just kinda blended in to all of the other " and ' around there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo '<form action="index.php" method="get">';
for ($i=0; $i<$_SESSION["fsize"];$i++)
{
    echo 'Type of Answer for Question ' . $i + 1 . ": <br> ";
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . '" value="radio">Radio Buttons <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . '" value="text">Text area <br>';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="f' . $i . '" value="Checkboxes">Checkboxes <br>
```

if you have more statements make sure to close it properly using `"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel really stupid now, it just kinda blended in to all of the other " and ' around there.

Comment: We all do make mistakes. :p

Answer (score 1):

This will be the answer from the Captain Obvious School of Web Design. 

Are you ready for it? ... 
**Be sure that you actually assign each radio button a value.** 
It took me 2.5 hours of (frustrating and confusing) research to realize that I had neglected to do this. Each button had a unique id assigned which I was expecting to be returned using:

`showAnswerWhen = $('input:radio[name="score"]:checked').val();`

Which (of course) had no effect on this HTML:

```
        <div class="pull-right score-bar">
            Show answers:
            <input type="radio" name="score" id="immediately"/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="immediately">Immediately</label>

            <input type="radio" name="score" id="when" checked/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="when">When I answer</label>

            <input type="radio" name="score" id="end"/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="end">At the end</label>
        </div><br/>
```

`showAnswerWhen` finally had the correct value (not just 'on') with the following HTML:

```
    <div class="pull-right score-bar">
            Show answers:
            <input type="radio" name="score" id="immediately" value="immediately"/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="immediately">Immediately</label>

            <input type="radio" name="score" id="when" value="when" checked/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="when">When I answer</label>

            <input type="radio" name="score" id="end" value="end"/>
            <label form="w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10" for="end">At the end</label>
        </div>
```

Turns out an id is not a value. So unreasonable! :-)